# Name for fluid that leaks out of phyllid (non-vascular) plants?

Tags: botany, terminology

As Wikipedia says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-vascular_plant):

> Consequently, phyllids are unable to control the rate of water loss from their tissues and are said to be poikilohydric.

And indeed, if you've touched these types of plants, they can feel wet and sometimes even slimy. Sometimes the liquid leaking out can look like dew drops, too.

Is there a proper term for this fluid? I thought *sap* at first, but it seems that term is reserved for vascular plants.

Comment: They often feel wet because they grow in damp environments, but you can absolutely dry a moss and re-hydrate it. Slimy texture might be external such as algae or it might be a product of the plant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a name for the external water, but the process of plant water loss is called "[transpiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpiration)", the evaporation of water from the tissues of a plant.

Note that the phenomena you describe, slimy plants or "dew drops", are not due to transpiration, as transpiration doesn't leave liquid water on the leaves. The sliminess you describe sounds more like plant mucus (mucilage).

The dew drops could be just that, external water. It also sounds like a something called "[guttation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttation)," a process in vascular plants where transpiration is decreased (such as at night) but [water pressure in the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_pressure) is high, basically pushing the water out of the leaf. This water is, essentially, sap, since it comes from the plant xylem. The [composition of guttation fluid](https://doi.org/10.1104/pp.41.3.373) is mainly glucose and some amino acids, which would give more of a sticky texture, while [mucilage is composed](https://doi.org/10.3390%2Fpolym13071066) of a mixture of highly branched carbohydrates and glycoproteins.

I'm not aware of guttation occurring in non-vascular plants, and it may be unlikely since they lack xylem and don't have many ways of slowing transpiration. However, guttation occurs in some [mushrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttation#/media/File:Hydnellum_peckii101.jpg), so roots and xylem are not an absolute requirement.